# Can't create aura definition bundle if there is already a lightning component bundle with the same name and namespace

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, deployment

*** Deploying with SOAP ***

````
MDAPI PROGRESS | ██████████████████████████████████████░░ | 41/43 Components

=== Component Failures [2]
TYPE   FILE                                            NAME          PROBLEM
─────  ──────────────────────────────────────────────  ────────────  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Error  mdapioutput/aura/FundTileList/FundTileList.cmp  FundTileList  Compilation Failure
                                                                        /c/Paginator/paginator.js:0,0 : LWC1010: Failed to resolve entry for module "paginator".
Error  mdapioutput/aura/Paginator                      Paginator     Can't create aura definition bundle if there is already a lightning component bundle with the same name and namespace.

ERROR running force:mdapi:deploy:  The metadata deploy operation failed.```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please remember titles should be concise and informative.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have both an Aura and LWC component with the same name. This is not allowed. You will want to delete or rename one of those components from the metadata files, presumably the Aura version. This may require some other refactoring of the code.